# how to check a utf-8 string contains unwanted character in php?

Tags: php, regex, string, utf-8

I have a string contains multi-language characters encoded by utf-8, and I want to check wether the string contains unwanted character.

I have created a regular expression of the white list of the characters, which is:

```
/[^0-9a-zａ-ｚ\u4e00-\u9fa5{}\s~`!@#$%^&*()_+=\-\[\];:'"<>,.?\/|\\。·？！、——‘’，；：“”（）《》……]/i
```

I have checked the preg_match() function, however it will return sub-strings which maches the regex.

How should I do that?

Comment: Can you list some examples for `unwanted character.`

Comment: Just check the start and end condition in your reg exp will yield you the required output:)

Answer (score 1):

The /u modifier tells the regexp engine to handle the pattern as an UTF-8 string.

Since it appears your pattern does contain UTF-8 characters, using this flag seems in order.

```
/[^0-9a-zａ-ｚ\u4e00-\u9fa5{}\s~`!@#$%^&*()_+=\-\[\];:'"<>,.?\/|\\。·？！、——‘’，；：“”（）《》……]/ui
```

Comment: +1 for better understanding the not-so-well-explained problem.

Comment: @anubhava Hehe thanks. Regexps are so bloody unreadable... I often prefer to write a parser instead. I can usually understand my parser's code after 6 months or so, but a couple of beers are enough to make me forget what yesterday's regexp was supposed to do :D